# Python - include a sum in a IF condition

Tags: python

It's probably a dumb question but I don't manage to put a sum expression in a If condition.
I work on a CSV file composed of 3 rows A, B and C.

Here is my code :

```
#import and export files

test = "/home/julien/excel/test.csv"
file1 = open (test, 'rb')

export_test = "/home/julien/excel/export_test.csv"
file2 = open (export_test, 'wb')

reader1 = csv.reader (file1, delimiter = ';', quotechar=' ')
writer1 = csv.writer (file2, delimiter= ';', quotechar=' ')


#conditions on test.csv

for row1 in reader1:
    A = row1[0]
    B = row1[1]
    C = row1[2]

    if (A + B) == C:
        writer1.writerow (["calcul ok"])
    else:
        writer1.writerow (["fail"])
```

The problem is that I only have "fail" results whereas it should not.

Could you help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Convert the strings into numbers:

```
A = float(row1[0])
B = float(row1[1])
C = float(row1[2])
```

Or more concisely:

```
A, B, C = map(float, row1[:3])
```

If your numbers are integers, replace `float` with `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because A, B and C are both `string`
When you `+` two strings, it means that you concat two `string` instead of sum them.

So, you need to convert it to number first

If it is a integer, you can convert it using:

```
num = int(a)
```

If it is a float, you can convert it using

```
num = float(a)
```

But if the number is float, you can't just compare it using `==`

Please refer this to check the equality of float
[Testing floating point equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python)