# Best way to detect floating round off error in python

Tags: python, floating-point

So I have a list of floating numbers, some of them have round off errors and appears in the form `0.3599999`. It is trivial to detect by convert it to string and see if there is a bunch of `999` following. I wonder how a python hacker will do for this or if there is a mathematical way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python

Comment: Try e^pi-pi. http://xkcd.com/217/

Comment: @Gandi: indeed, it looks like [19.99909997919](http://ideone.com/OhFJTy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Python's decimal module

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.35)
Decimal('0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at Numpy's [`assert_approx_equal()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal.html) function:

```
>>> np.testing.assert_approx_equal(0.12345677777777e-20, 0.1234567e-20)
>>> np.testing.assert_approx_equal(0.12345670e-20, 0.12345671e-20,
                               significant=8)
>>> np.testing.assert_approx_equal(0.12345670e-20, 0.12345672e-20,
                               significant=8)
...
<type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>:
Items are not equal to 8 significant digits:
 ACTUAL: 1.234567e-021
 DESIRED: 1.2345672000000001e-021
```