# Stopping a turtle when it reaches a point, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am currently in a beginning programming class, and I am blowing through the assignments. Right now, I have to make 3 houses with the module turtle (which I accomplished):

```
def drawBody(mover):
    #Rectangle part
    mover.fillcolor("blue")
    mover.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        mover.forward(100)
        mover.right(90)
        mover.forward(75)
        mover.right(90)
    mover.end_fill()


    #Triangle part
    mover.fillcolor("red")
    mover.begin_fill()
    mover.left(45)
    for i in range(2):
        mover.forward(70.5)
        mover.right(90)
    mover.right(45)
    mover.forward(100)
    mover.end_fill()







#Create preproduction turtle
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
josh = turtle.Turtle()


pointGoTo = -175
for houses in range(3):
    josh.penup()
    josh.goto(pointGoTo,0)
    josh.pendown()

    drawBody(josh)


    josh.right(180)
    pointGoTo = pointGoTo + 125

wn.exitonclick()
```

here is the while code. So I want the turtle to stop at a certain point, The top left corner of the red square. I have tried multiple points but the while just doesnt break/stop. Is my syntax off? or am I approaching this whole line of the house thing all wrong? If i am being vague, please ask what you dont understand, I really want to figure this out, but i am all out of ideas.:

```
def drawBody(mover):
    #Rectangle part
    mover.fillcolor("blue")
    mover.begin_fill()
    for i in range(2):
        mover.forward(100)
        mover.right(90)
        mover.forward(75)
        mover.right(90)
    mover.end_fill()


    #Triangle part
    mover.fillcolor("red")
    mover.begin_fill()
    mover.left(45)
    for i in range(2):
        mover.forward(70.5)
        mover.right(90)
    mover.right(45)
    mover.forward(100)
    mover.end_fill()

    mover.left(90)
    mover.forward(75)
    mover.left(90)
    n = mover.position()
    print(n)
    while True:
        mover.forward(100)
        n = mover.position()
        print(n)
        mover.left(90)
        mover.forward(5)
        mover.left(90)
        n = mover.position()
        print(n)
        mover.forward(100)
        mover.right(90)
        mover.forward(5)
        mover.right(90)


        if n == (-75.30,0.00):
            break







#Create preproduction turtle
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
josh = turtle.Turtle()


pointGoTo = -175
for houses in range(3):
    josh.penup()
    josh.goto(pointGoTo,0)
    josh.pendown()

    drawBody(josh)


    josh.right(180)
    pointGoTo = pointGoTo + 125

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you expect the turtle to reach that point? Can you figure out how many iterations it will take? Why not just only loop for that long? Can you not just pull the pen up and move the turtle there? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Yes, It gets to that point in the while loop. But the while loop keeps going. so it keeps making these lines : http://puu.sh/4xkPg.png. I want the line to stop at the top of the blue.

Comment: Hint: Do you know how many of those lines you want it to make? Maybe you can write an equation that will tell you how many lines are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you're checking in the wrong place, you ahve to check it here:

```
while True:
    mover.forward(100)

    mover.left(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.left(90)
    n = mover.position()

    if abs(n - (-75.30, 0.00)) < 0.01:
        break

    mover.forward(100)
    mover.right(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.right(90)
```

Your check is not succesfull because n is actually [turtle.Vec2D](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.Vec2D), and coordinates are float, you can see it if you do `print n[0], n[1]`. There're many links on SO about comparing floats, like [Testing floating point equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python), for example. In your case you can do:

```
if abs(n - (-75.30, 0.00)) < 0.01:
    break
```

But I think, the best way for you would be to just paint fixed amount of times:

```
mover.left(90)
mover.forward(70)
mover.left(90)
for i in xrange(7):
    mover.forward(100)
    mover.left(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.left(90)

    mover.forward(100)
    mover.right(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.right(90)
```

Also you have to change your code like this:

```
for houses in range(3):
    josh.penup()
    josh.goto(pointGoTo,0)
    josh.pendown()

    drawBody(josh)

    pointGoTo = pointGoTo + 125
```

Answer (score 0):

In here you want a stop condition.

```
while True:
    mover.forward(100)
    n = mover.position()
    print(n)
    mover.left(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.left(90)
    n = mover.position()
    print(n)
    mover.forward(100)
    mover.right(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.right(90)
```

You can either try and use the mover's position, or you can count the number of times it must move.

If you use the mover's position you will have to do calculations to offset from where the square starts and what direction you're going in (especially if you're at a 30° angle!), so I don't recommend that.

Instead, you can say that the square (which is blue, btw, not red) is 75px tall and you move up by 10 each iteration, so you want 7½ iterations. If you had a whole number of iterations, say 8, you could've done

```
for i in range(8):
    mover.forward(100)
    n = mover.position()
    ...
```

which counts the iterations 0..7 (there are 8 numbers from 0 to 7) and does an iteration each time. We want to break from the loop on the final, 8<sup>th</sup> iteration, which is easy because we have the `break` keyword and the `i` variable from the `range` keeps track of the number of iterations:

```
for i in range(8):
    mover.forward(100)
    n = mover.position()
    print(n)
    mover.left(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.left(90)
    n = mover.position()
    print(n)

    if i == 7:
        break

    mover.forward(100)
    mover.right(90)
    mover.forward(5)
    mover.right(90)
```

Note that `i == 7` happens on the **8<sup>th</sup>** iteration, so the 8<sup>th</sup> is cancelled half-way, so 7½ iterations, moving 75 pixels upwards, are done.