# Python: Semantics of Comparing Lists

Tags: python, list, rounding

Everyone.

I've come into a strange problem where when I try to compare two identical lists, Python (2.7) determines that they are disparate. They are embedded in a rather large body of code, but here is small piece of it.

```
print("innersearch:",innersearch)
print("innersub:",innersub)
if (innersearch == innersub):
     print("innersearch = innersub")
print("----")
```

Unfortunately, this returns:

```
innersearch: (-100.00,-0.00)
innersub: (-100.00,-0.00)
----
```

I know this is a modal issue, because when I replace `innersearch` and `innersub` with `(-100.00,-0.00)` for both, I get `innersearch = innersub`. Any help is appreciated, and apologies for my lack of knowledge.

UPDATE:

It was suggested that I round the values, as they had been when outputted before comparing them, and, unfortunately, this did little to help.

```
innersub = turtle.Vec2D(round(innersub[0], 2), round(innersub[1], 2))
innersearch = turtle.Vec2D(round(innersearch[0], 2), round(innersearch[1], 2))
print("innersearch:",innersearch)
print("innersub:",innersub)
if (innersearch == innersub):
    print("innersearch = innersub")
print("----")
```

And this returned the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Are they lists or tuples?

Comment: My guess is that there's a very slight difference in the floating point values, such that they both round to the same number when displayed, but they're not actually equal.

Comment: Add a couple lines of debug code to test @daowen's hypothesis: `for i in xrange(len(list1)): print list1[i] - list2[i]`.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never compare floats with `==`.

Comment: @Xymostech: that would make *no difference*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java . The question is about Java, but the same rules apply to floats in Python and collections containing floats in Python.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what *are* the objects?  Standard Python tuples wouldn't look like that -- the spacing is wrong -- and standard Python floats wouldn't show two decimals.  So there's at least one nonstandard type involved.  What are `type(innersearch)` and `type(innersearch[0])` (assuming the latter works)?

Comment: There coordinates, for turtle module. Sorry, I didn't realize that may have been salient; I was trying to shorten my questions to just the relevant information.

Comment: @DaoWen: I'm interested in your explanation. Would you recommend I round the values before I compare them, and, if so, how?

Comment: You can look at *[Floating point equality in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python)* for some more info on how you should compare floating point numbers.

Comment: How did you get the -0 values in the first place?

Comment: The `-0.00` is just the way the module names the coordinates.

Comment: @DaoWen, with the new information, any help?

Comment: Knowing that these are `turtle.Vec2D` objects rather than native tuples provides a clue. Does `turtle.Vec2D` implement the equality operator?

Comment: Are you leaving anything out here? Are you really just comparing two Vec2Ds with two entries, or did you simplify that for the example? @qwrrty - Yes, they derive from Tuple and implement equality.

Comment: @5813: No, normally (with normal arithmetic or by initializing a Vec2D object) you don't get negative zero, only if you explicitly define it as such, So where exactly do innersearch and innersub come from? What is their repr()?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys, but I got it with the help of @user2357112, by rounding the values.

Answer (score 2):

Two lists are considered equal if, and only if, both lists have the same length and each element in the first list compares equal to the corresponding element in the second. That's roughly:

```
def lists_equals(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2):
        return False
    return all(a == b for (a, b) in zip(l1, l2))
```

An important thing to note is that equality semantics are *not* automatically defined for custom classes -- or rather, they default to identity. In the absence of an `__eq__` method, two objects only compare as equal if they are the *same* object (`a == b` behaves exactly like `a is b`).

What this means is that if your lists contain instances of classes you wrote yourself and you want to be able to compare those lists, said classes must implement `__eq__`, or your comparisons won't work.