# Replace a value based on specific criteria

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do a file manipulation and reassignment where the file has 4 columns like:

The file has 2514 rows and 4 columns the format is:

```
1 -0.000000 0.000000 0    
2 -0.000000 0.000000 0    
3 -7.009116 58.185083 1    
4 -7.009116 58.185670 1    
5 -7.009799 58.185410 0    
6 -7.009996 58.184643 1    
7 -7.009997 58.186257 1    
8 -7.012637 58.182443 1    
9 -7.013223 58.182150 1    
10 -7.010877 58.184203 1
```

My goal is to load the file into Python and based on the `x,y` set values which I will set as criteria they will changes the flag value to a number I desire for example

for `x=-7.00` and variable y that start from `y=58.1` up to `63.5` then change the the 4th column into 2 (or 3 or 4)

I have thought of something but I dont know how to express the criterion I mentioned and then write a new file with the same format but new flags.

```
from numpy import *

fname='put the name here'

a='' #x-coordinates
b='' #y-coordinates

data = loadtxt("battri.node") 

nodes=data[:,0]

x=data[:,1]
y=data[:,2]  
flag=data[:,3]

for x=a:
   for y=>b:

?????? I believe here i have to set the criterion but I cant find the correct expression

fid= open(fname+'_2.node','a')

fid.write('')
```

Comment: can you give an example of desired output?

Comment: Hello. What is the set of replacing values for the flag ? Are they all of one-character long ?

Comment: It is exactly like this the only difference after the manipulation should be in the last column
for e.g

2514 2 0 1



1 -0.000000 0.000000 2


2 -0.000000 0.000000 1


3 -7.009116 58.185083 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this avoiding the for loops and obtaining a better performance using NumPy fancy indexing to apply the criteria (EDIT2: I replaced `x==-7.00` by a tolerance-based criterion):

```
TOL = 0.001
crit1 = (abs((abs(x)-7.00))<TOL) & (y>=58.1) & (y<63.5)
flag[crit1] = 2

...
```

After applying all the criteria you can directly print `data` since `x`, `y`, `z` and `flag` were actually views of the original 2-D array `data`:

```
np.savetxt('output_file_name', data)
```

---

EDIT: an example of how the complete code would look like:

```
from numpy import *

a='' #x-coordinates
b='' #y-coordinates

data = loadtxt("battri.node") 

nodes=data[:,0]

x=data[:,1]
y=data[:,2]  
flag=data[:,3]

crit1 = (x==-7.00) & (y>=58.1) & (y<63.5)
flag[crit1] = 2

savetxt('output_file_name', data)
```

Comment: Just to check i wrote 
crit1 = (x==-7.00) & (y==58.1)
Although it returns me a True, False statement, seems that it detects the pair but does not change the flag column
Here is the text :

[array([False, False,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)]

Comment: @user3393764 After you find the criterion in `crit1`, you have to use this array of `True`s and `False`s to change the data of flag doing `flag[crit1]=2`, which means that when the criterion is True, apply the new value...

Comment: How will i manage that?
I wrote something like this
crit1 = (x==-7.009116) 

crit2 = (y==58.185083) 

crit3 =  (y<58.186257)

if [crit1,crit2,crit3] = True

flag[crit1,crit2,crit3] = 2

BUt it is not correct

Sorry again for the questions, but I am fairly new to python and try to get my head around it..thank you all for your patience

Comment: @user3393764 I edited the answer giving an example of how the full code would look like...

Comment: @ Saullo Castro, thank for your help in advance , although this time it is running the finalized output does not have the flags altered.
I reduced the criteria as well, making both equal so as to see if it will change at least one position
.Although it returns the values in the new file in just a double format(more numbers after the decimal)

Comment: @user3393764 the format can be controlled passing the `fmt` argument: `savetxt(..., fmt=['%d', '%1.6f', '%1.6f', '%d'])`, if this approach is not working, it would be nice to check your input file, if you could make it available...

Comment: @ Saullo Castro, I have pasted on the top of the question (top of page) the first 20 lines from the files, it basically represents a mesh with number of node(1st column), x-coord and y-coord (2-3rd column) and the flag (identification) number for a boundary at the last column

Comment: @user3393764 I guess I know where your problem is, instead of using x==-7.00, you should use a tolerance like (abs((abs(x)-7.00))<TOL), and your criterion should work...

Comment: @ Saullo Castro, i did the alteration

crit1 = (abs((abs(x)-7.00))<TOL) & (y>=58.184) & (y<59)
flag[crit1] = 2

savetxt('test.node',data,'%1.3f')

but the output txt does not change the flag

Comment: @ Saullo Castro, to simplify it a bit i told it to identify only x and y with specific values
it1 = (abs((abs(x)-7.00))<TOL) & (y==58.185)  that i took from the file, but even through that trial the flag are unchanged.

Comment: @user3393764 the problem now is that you are using a strict check for y, try to apply a tolerance for this variable too

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not only  want to define a set of criteria, but also actions / rules to act upon them. Therefore I would define them as a series of transforms in the form of Python functions.

Python has [first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), so you can pass functions as arguments to other functions:

Something like this:

```
data = [(1, 2.5, 1.0, 99),
        (2, 7.0, 2.5, 99),
        (3, 1.0, 2.5, 99)]


def transform1(nodes, x, y, flag):
    if x == 7.0 and 0.0 < y < 5.0:
        flag = 77
    return nodes, x, y, flag


def transform2(nodes, x, y, flag):
    if x == 1.0:
        flag = 42
    return nodes, x, y, flag


# Will be applied in order
transforms = [transform1, transform2]


result = []
for row in data:
    for transform in transforms:
        transformed = transform(*row)
    result.append(transformed)

print result
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2.5, 1.0, 99),
 (2, 7.0, 2.5, 99),
 (3, 1.0, 2.5, 42)]
```

Comment: @ Lukas Graf, I kept the first the lines that load the files and classify the quantities inside.
when i applied the coding the print result, was 'None'.
I thought perhaps its because the x== i was defining was -7.00 while the files, due to the fact that are created in Matlab have more numbers after the decimal point. I thought that Python would be able to "grab" any number that starts with -7.00 (even if after it has more number e.g. -7.001234, am i also mistaken there?)
changed both x and y according to the a numeric value within the file but still the result was 'None'

Comment: Testing floating point values for equality is a somewhat tricky business, you'd need to define a tolerance. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a couple questions here. Let's start with reading in the data:

Python's `file` class has a useful function called `readlines()`, which will return a list containing each line in a file. IE:

```
lines = []
with open('filename.txt') as file:
     lines = file.readlines()
```

You can then iterate over this list and convert it into a tuple of values, and then transform the values:

```
transformed_data = []
for line in lines:
    node, x, y, flag = line.split()
    # Do transform on values here
    transformed_data.append(' '.join([node, x, y, flag])
```

Finally you can write out the data to a file directly:

```
with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
     file.write(transformed_data)
```

If that first line is a header, you'll have to account for that, but that's pretty trivial to do. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for reading/writing files for more on how to do that.