# Python float comparison

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a problem to understand the following python `if` clause.

```
key = '033411943470228118020044104711300230269019812152152'    
my_secret = hex(int(key[0:3]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(key[4:7]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(key[8:11]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(key[12:15]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(key[16:19]))[2:].zfill(2) 

    if float(my_secret) == 4.74678e+018:
```

Can anybody tell me how I can construct the my_secret that causes the if clause to be true?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic strikes again.

Comment: `my_secret = "4.74678e+018"` works for me, although comparing floats for equality is general doesn't necessarily do what you might expect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point equality in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python)

Comment: my_secret is '217715be4b4', that is not in base 10 or 12. For example, int(my_secret, base=16) returns 2299709351092, but it is probably wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_secret = 4.74678e+018
```

Except when it's not: don't use floats for exact quantities!

Not all numbers can be represented as floats, so you might have rounding errors, which will lead to unexpected results when making exact comparisons.

Comment: i just added to my code how my secret is derived thats the reason why i don't understand it

Comment: @Martin In the code you're showing, `my_secret` is a  string, it's not the best idea to compare that to a float..

Comment: @Martin No, you didn't. For that being complete, you'd have to tell us what `key` is.

Comment: thats an existing coding i got that i reverse engineered

Comment: just added the key definition