# How a Python newbie might overcome problems with floating point comparisons

Tags: python, floating-point

Sorry for a long question, and for code that's not truly minimal.

I have a very limited understanding of the thorniness of floating-point comparisons.
I have read some python docs and tutorials on the topic. I have read some SO discussions such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029397/1445400.

However, I don't know how to apply responses such as "why aren't you using str(value)" or "just format it with %" or "you have to use Decimal".  My favorite theme is "just ignore the 11th decimal place differences... they don't really matter, and you can get the right aesthetics in the end if you format the response as a string."  I don't know how to make that work in my application.

Here's my code, which might look like homework, but truly isn't.  I'm calculating the intersections of a grid of lines spanning a non-rectangular polygon.  I generate a rectangle, move one or more of the corners, then draw and redraw grids on the polygon, so I need to calculate where the grid lines begin, end, and cross.

```
def partition_boundaries(start, stop, number_of_partitions):
    interval = (stop - start)/number_of_partitions
    l = [start, stop]
    i = 1
    while i < number_of_partitions:
        l.insert(i, start + i*interval)
        i += 1
    return l

def test():
    test_cases = [
                  ((0.0, 1.0, 2), [0, .5, 1]), 
                  ((0.0, 1.0, 4), [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]), 
                  ]
    passes = 0
    for (args, expected_result) in test_cases:
        result = partition_boundaries(*args)
        if result != expected_result:
            print "Failed for: ", args, ".  Expected: ", expected_result, " Got: ", result
        else:
            passes = passes + 1
    print passes, " out of ", len(test_cases), " test cases passed."

test()
```

This produces output like:
Failed for:  (0.0, 1.0, 4) .  Expected:  [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75000000000000011, 1.0]  Got:  [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]

It's frustrating to believe something this simple requires arcane maneuvers like turning numbers into strings and back again, or writing my own function to compare the absolute value of differences to a tolerance, etc. "It shouldn't be this hard", but maybe I need to get over myself.  It also makes me nervous about getting to a place where I can "gently" introduce my kid to "real" programming.

I'm not doing financial accounting, and don't need lots and lots of significant figures.

For this code, how do you recommend I proceed with my beginner's education?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point equality testing is a difficult matter.  I don't know of anything in Python that will change the fundamental floating point comparison built into the language, but you could write a function that returns `True` if two numbers are close, where close can be defined in relative or absolute terms, e.g.

```
def almost_equal(x,y):
    epsilon = 0.00001
    return abs(x-y) < epsilon
```

Then you would write another function to test 'equality' of your structure, using `almost_equal` in place of `==` for any floating point compares.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding floating points is not difficult. There are two things to remember: 1) Like in a calculator, you have only a limited number of digits (usually around 16). 2) The increments are not in decimal steps but in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) steps. With the help of [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), the resolution of different values can be easily determined:

```
import numpy as np

for p in range(-5,5):
     pp = 10**p
     print("{:6g}: {}".format(pp, np.spacing(pp)))
```

gives:

```
 1e-05: 1.69406589451e-21
0.0001: 1.35525271561e-20
 0.001: 2.16840434497e-19
  0.01: 1.73472347598e-18
   0.1: 1.38777878078e-17
     1: 2.22044604925e-16
    10: 1.7763568394e-15
   100: 1.42108547152e-14
  1000: 1.13686837722e-13
 10000: 1.81898940355e-12
```

This means for example that `1 + 2.22044604925e-16 == 1` is `False` but `10 + 2.22044604925e-16 == 10` is `True`. As @OldGeeksGuide pointed you need do an approximate comparison depending on the magnitude. See also Numpy's [allclose()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) for an appropriate comparison