# Unexpected behavior of floating point comparisons

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have written a small python program which gets stuck in a loop for reasons unknown to me.

This is my code:

```
a = 0
b = 1
step = 0.1

while True:
    if a == b:
        print 'exit'
        break
    if a < b:
        a += step
        print a
    if a > b:
        a -= step
        print a
```

This is the output:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
1.1
1.0
1.1
1.0
[...]
```

Why doesn't the loop terminate, but even yield values larger than 1?

**EDIT:**

I've done it now with the decimal module:

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 1

a = 0
b = 1
step = Decimal('0.1')

while True:
    if a == b:
        print 'exit'
        break
    if a < b:
        a += step
        print a
    if a > b:
        a -= step
        print a
```

Comment: Floating point numbers almost never compare equally. http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: @deceze You should put that in an answer.

Comment: @Frank I'm sure there's a great duplicate somewhere that someone will whip out momentarily because they're at home in the `python` tag... Martijn...? :)

Comment: for example: [Floating point equality in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python)

Comment: maybe you should use if()...elif()...else... structure. and the floating variables not compare correctly.

Comment: When you change the print statements to `print repr(a)` you see the actual value of the variable.

Comment: Other possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5595425/1025391

Comment: Thank you guys! I didn't know that floating point numbers are not equal. And sorry for being too stupid to search the right threats.

Answer (score 1):

Your should never check equality of floating point values. Best way is to use constraint on error.

```
if abs(a - b) <= allowed_error :
    do something
```