# How to check if the sum of floats equals a number and accounting for Floating Point Inaccuracy

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to check if a sum of floating point numbers adds up to 100. And of course they don't, due to floating point accuracy.

So, what doesn't work is:

```
test = [99.9, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.025]
sum(test) == 100.
```

alternatively

```
sum(test) > 99.99999 and sum(test) < 100.0000001
```

works fine, but I consider it as ugly, because the limits are arbitrary. Is there a more elegant method in python to check float numbers on equality? Or at least a method to choose the limits not only arbitrary but based on the internal accuracy?

Comment: You could just test whether `abs(sum(test) - 100) < epsilon`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/floating-point-equality-in-python

Comment: The sum of the things in that array is about 5.69 * 10^(-15) larger than 100.  Are you sure you want the two to compare equal?