# maximum recursion depth exceeded in minimum payment program

Tags: python, recursion

Below error occurs indicating base case is not reached, by I don't know why it is the case. I am using bisection search for a debt payment problem:

I want to find out the smallest payment such that outstanding can be paid off within a year (-0.1 < outstanding after 12 months < 0)

```
File "problem3.py", line 21, in calculate
    calculate(balance, annualInt, min, lower, upper)
File "problem3.py", line 5, in calculate
    while month < 12 and outstanding > 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

My code:

```
#find the smallest monthly payment such that we can pay off the debt within a
#year
def calculate(balance, annualInt, minpay, lower, upper):
    outstanding = balance
    monInt = annualInt/ 12.0
    month = 0
    while month < 12 and outstanding > 0:
        outstanding = round((outstanding*(1+monInt) - minpay),2)
        month += 1

    if outstanding < 0 and outstanding > -0.1: # set outstanding range (-0.1 < x < 0)
        print('Montly payment to pay off debt in 1 year:', round(minpay,2))
        print('Number of months needed:', month)
        print('Balance:', round((outstanding),2))
    elif outstanding <= -0.1:
        upper = minpay
        minpay = round(((lower + upper) /2.0), 2)
        calculate(balance, annualInt, minpay, lower, upper)
    else:
        lower = minpay
        minpay = round(((lower + upper)/ 2.0), 2)
        calculate(balance, annualInt, minpay, lower, upper)

balance = round(float(input('Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card:')),2)
annualInt = round(float(input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal')),2)
# set lower to  Monthly payment lower bound
lower = balance / 12.0
# set lowet to Monthly payment upper bound
upper = (balance*(1+(annualInt/12.0))**12.0)/12.0
# set minpay to the smallest monthly payment
minpay = round(((lower + upper)/2.0), 2)

calculate(balance, annualInt, minpay, lower, upper)
```

Comment: Any of your condition is wrong which is making your code go infinite recursion

Comment: You shouldn't also use `min` name for variable, coz it's python builtin.

Comment: I think that is a problem too but I don't figure out which condition is wrong and why, since I think conditions cover all ranges.

Comment: You are calling this recursively until you get to `outstanding < 0 and outstanding > -0.1`. This never happens for some inputs. Try `print outstanding` every time to see what is going on.

Comment: You're right . I should not have used min.

Comment: outstanding after 12 months never reaches 0.03, and repeat this figure(0.03) over and over again.

Comment: Does this mean range is too strict for a value(outstanding) to reach the base case ?

Comment: Why do you do this recursively in the first place? A `while` loop should work as well. Not to mention this can just be *calculated* directly...

Comment: When doing floating point arithmetic, it's important to understand that all values are _approximate_ and code accordingly. For example, rather than check if something is exactly `0.0`, check to see if it's close to it instead. See [_Testing floating point equality_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028889/testing-floating-point-equality).

Comment: I understand your point but in my code I specify the range rather than the exact value.